# How can I build an IOS app on IOS?

Tags: ios, codea

I've made an app with Codea and exported to an XCode project. Is there way to build it on IOS (or windows)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely.

Some folks over at iNinjas have successfully ported the Clang-LLVM toolchain to run on iOS. [Here's a download link](http://ininjas.com/repo/debs/clang-llvm_3.1-1_iphoneos-arm.deb) - install the deb on your iOS device. You will also have to copy the development sysroot (the `iPhoneOSX.Y.sdk` folder) from your computer to your mobile device. **The device also has to be jailbroken.**

(I don't remember exactly if there are any other packages to install, but perhaps odcctools from Cydia, etc, just google it.)

After that, you have to compile and link all the files. Of course, Xcode uses a proprietary format for project files, so you can't just go ahead and expect the compiler to build from the Xcode project, but you have to, for example, write a Makefile to specify that all `.m` files are to be compiled. Then you will have an executable file which you may or may not need to codesign.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a tutorial on creating an app from your Codea/Xcode project:
http://codeatuts.blogspot.nl/2012/08/tutorial-12-submitting-to-app-store.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you already have a mac, you can use Dringend to compile it from your iPad.  It requires a program running on your mac that will do that actual compiling, and then send the file back to Dringend on your iPad, which will install it.  This requires having a mac, but will let you program on your iPad away from your mac.  This also requires an iOS developer license, for the code signing identities.